# How to click link icon with laravel dusk?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk

If I have a link:

```
<a href="/somewhere">Click Me</a>
```

I know I can `clickLink` based on its text.

```
public function testCanClickLink()
{
    $this->browse(function ($browser) {
        $browser->visit('/welcome')
                ->clickLink('Click Me');
    });
}
```

But how can I click an icon link?

```
<a href="/somewhere">
    <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can target the href like this:

`->click('a[href="/somewhere"]')`

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit hacky, but it's what I've come up with as a workaround.

1. Put an id selector on the link.

   ```
   <a id="link-click-me" href="/somewhere">
       <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </a>
   ```
2. Assert it's visible.
3. Get the href attribute.
4. Visit it.
5. Assert path is correct.

   ```
   public function testCanClickLink()
   {
       $this->browse(function ($browser) {
           $browser->visit('/welcome')
                   ->assertVisible('#link-click-me')
                   ->visit(
                       $browser->attribute('#link-click-me', 'href')
                   )
                   ->assertPathIs('/somewhere');
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: This does not preform click action, which subsequently causes redirect. Therefore if there would be running some broken javascript on page, which would prevent redirection by user's click, this approach will not prevent us from headache.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same doubt... and worst, I couldn't use href as a reference to clickable element because I just needed to open a modal. So, my solution was use the **dusk** attribute, like this:

```
<a dusk="link-click-me" href="">
    <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

And... in my test code, run this line:

```
$browser->click('@link-click-me');
```

Enjoy! o/